# Switch to a Lightning experience

Tags: lightning, salesforce-classic

What should I do in order to switch to a Lightning experience? Lol, I thought it is an easy thing to do, but then I got stuck. I googled and [here](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-to-switch-between-Salesforce-Classic-and-Lightning-Experience) is what I found:

> To switch to Lightning Experience from Salesforce Classic, click your name in the Salesforce Classic header, then click **Switch to Lightning Experience**.

And here is the screenshot of the attempt to do that:
[image]

I can not find the **Switch to Lightning Experience** button, help me, please.

Does the following screenshot mean that I won`t be able to use Lightning Experience with IE?

[image]

Are there any roundabouts to be able to use Lightning Experience with IE?

Here is the IE version I am using:

[image]

> Version: 11.165.17134.0

In [the](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browsers_sfx.htm&type=5) documentation it is said that I should be able to use Lightning Experience, but still I can not. What else can I try?

[image]

Comment: Assuming you are a system admin, which browser you are using?

Comment: Check the Enable Lightning module at Salesforce Trailhead: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lex_migration_introduction/units/lex_migration_introduction_administration

Comment: What version of IE are you using? See this for browser compatibility: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browsers_sfx.htm&type=5

Comment: You missed this part in the documentation: "IMPORTANT Support for Internet Explorer 11 to access Lightning Experience is retiring beginning in Summer ’16.
You can continue to use IE11 to access Lightning Experience until December 16, 2017.
If you opt in to Extended Support for IE11, you can continue to use IE11 to access Lightning Experience and Communities until December 31, 2020." You must opt-in. How? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000233325&type=1

Comment: In general though you should not be building any habit or business process around accessing Lightning from IE 11. Going forward only modern browsers will be supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you enable Lightning for the org, you have to grant permissions to your users in their Profile or in a Permission Set.  Make sure the "Lightning Experience user" permission has been granted to your user.

To enable lightning to a profile, go to that profile and search for 'Lightning' and turn on 'Lightning Experience User'. This should help:

[image]

Also these buttons will help knowing that you are just getting started:

[image]

Comment: Could you, please, provide a guide or a link on how to grant these kinds of permissions?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/ --> you can search within salsforce for the documentation and guides

Comment: Added some screenshots that should help.